# How convert wchar_t to unicode number?

Tags: c, unicode

How convert wchar value into number in unicode table?

I have a variable:

```
wchar_t znak;
znak=getwchar();
```

I type 'ą' how convert znak to #261
I need number in unicode table.

ą U+0105 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH OGONEK

UTF-16: 0x0105

XML: & # 261;

Comment: `0x105` (base-16) *is* `261` (base-10).

Answer (score 5):

The standard didn't specify `sizeof(wchar_t)` (or its encoding), so you should have stated what system you are on.

#### Assuming *nix (Linux, BSD, OSX etc.)

`wchar_t` is 32 bits and stores UTF-32 code points, which is a fixed-length encoding. You could use `znak` directly with no conversion needed.

Although you should first check whether UTF-8 and `char` aren't better up to your task (For conversion, UTF-32 is certainly better, but your program might do more than that).

If you determine that UTF-8 is an overall better choice for your program, you can use [`mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) to get a UTF-32 code point out of your UTF-8 code point.

#### Assuming Windows

`wchar_t` is 16 bits and stores UTF-16LE code units. For Console I/O you are limited to UCS-2 though. The difference lies in that UTF-16 is not a fixed length encoding. So-called Surrogate pairs (albeit rare) allow the representation of non-[BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) code points.

So in your case, just using using `znak` directly will work too.

For completion sake's though, here is a possible implementation [from the UTF-16 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Example_code):

```
u32 read_code_point_from_utf16()
{
  u16 code_unit = getu16();
  if (code_unit >= 0xD800 && code_unit <= 0xDBFF) {
    u16 code_unit_2 = getu16();
    if (code_unit_2 >= 0xDC00 && code_unit_2 <= 0xDFFF)
       return (code_unit << 10) + code_unit_2 - 0x35FDC00;
    push_back(code_unit_2);
  }
return code_unit;
}
```

Finally, use `sprintf(s, "&#%d;", znak)` and `sprintf(s, "0x%x", znak)` to get it into the required base.

Comment: Minor: `"0x%04x` instead of `"0x%x`.